# Game puzzle pop in java

Tags: java, gui

I am making a game in Java based of those puzzle popping games.
The objective is to select with the mouse and remove a tile. [The game i want to build](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BubblePoke.MobileAppsPro&hl=en).
I have a JPanel and on top, several Components, a board[][], of type Tile. Tile has a BufferedImage and a Color as background.
How to make a tile, which is a BufferedImage, change its state, for example, change color or remove it from a array[][] using a mouse click.
I have 4 classes,[link to pastebin, didnt want to put 4 classes here](http://pastebin.com/tBxJHwSm)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Do you want to know how to handle mouse event? Or is it about how your data structures work? Please be specific.

Comment: My problem is, how to change a GUI with Images objects, so that when I click them, these tiles are modified, if it's still unclear, say so.

Comment: Yes, it is still unclear where exactly your problem lies.

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: There still just isn't a clear question here that could provide value to others or that others could easily read and contribute to. Even the only answer says that he didn't have time to read all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the Tile class is the class of which all the "balls" are an object of? (i dont have much time to read the code).

If i understand correctly, what you are asking is how to change the balls color? if yes, i would suggest that when you want to change a balls color just get the tiles from your Tiles array and just:

```
board[x][y].background = //the new color;
```

EDIT:

Use (i write the code directly here so there may be some mistakes :/):

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();
    for(Tile[] balls : board[]){
      for(Tile ball : balls){
        if(mouseover(mx,my,ball)){
          //check if surrounding balls have the dame color, and if they do "break" them/change their color
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

and the mouseover() function would be something like :

```
 private boolean mouseOver(int mx, int my ,Tile ball){
     //width and height is the width/height off the balls
    if(mx <= ball.x + width && mx >= ball.x){
        if(my <= ball.y + height && my >= ball.y){
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }else return false;


}
```

I think this should work....or at least i hope so :D

Comment: Yes, I feel you somewhat understood my problem. How would you do that with a mouse event?Namely, MouseClicked().

Comment: will your window be resizable?

Comment: it can be, its not right now I think.

Comment: if its not its pretty easy: i will edit my post in 1 min

Comment: For now i can make the JPanel detect mouse clicks, but I dont know how to make the other components that are on top of JPanel be modified by mouse clicks, I think this is the question I should have asked first

Comment: also your class must : extends MouseAdapter

Comment: no problem :D (notify me if you want any explanation or further help)

Comment: @DanielMonteiro if my answer solved your problem please press the "accept answer" button (under the down arrow next to my ansswer) so your question will be considered closed.